# Google Sign In for websites: Can't render sign-in button

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-signin, google-openid

I am following the official guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and can't get a button to render.  I'm not a front-end dev but have to get this working to demonstrate some backend functionality.  Since the guide might assume some things that are obvious to front-end devs, I'll explain what I did to achieve the guide steps.

- Under "Load the Google Platform Library", I put that `<script>` tag under the `<head>` tag
- Under "Specify your app's client ID", I put that, with my clientId substituted, also under the `<head>` tag, directly before the `<script>` from previous step
- Under "Add a Google Sign-In button", I placed that `<div>` Tag somewhere in the body of my page, next to a `<p>` tag that successfully renders text (to be sure I wasn't in a hidden div)

At this point, when I refresh my page, I cannot see the sign-in button anywhere.  Thinking it might have to do with the JS function from the next step missing, I added that function within the `<body>` tag, directly after I open the `<body>` tag.

Still no button.  I tried to put the code in jsfiddle, like another user suggested, but I couldn't figure out even where to put `<script>` and `<meta>` tags in jsfiddle, because when I entered a `<head>` tag, JSFiddle told me that it was already included for me, but I could not find it to add my tags to it.

I took all my application code out and created a bare page with just the bits from Google to demonstrate how I'm trying to use the library.  I've pasted that code to pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/M1ux89ZQ)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can use [Google's Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) template to initialize the login & grant of permissions process in a slightly more elegant manner:

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{{ OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID }}">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="google-signin-button"
     class="g-signin2"
     data-width="170"
     data-height="30"
     data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
     data-onfailure="onSignInFailure">
</div>
```

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
}

function onSignOut(){
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut();
}
```